# import bulk images to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am migrating a very big website to wordpress. 
I have about 35,000 images that I need to migrate to the wordpress environment from a custom cms made in native php.

I have uploaded the files via ftp to the `wp-content` directory but the wordpress media does not seem to recognize it, since it's missing the meta data in the mysql database.

I found the "add from server" plugin, but that plugin is limited to manually selecting images but when I select many images at once, it crashes.

Are there any other solution out there?

Comment: i wrote that i tried this plugin, it's not working for many directories and files and require one by one selection

Comment: from which platform you are migrating to wordpress

Comment: it's a site written in native php with it's own cms

Comment: have you gone through the database. first check the image storing process of old website then make sql script to migrate their path with post_id in `$wpdb->postmeta` because wordpress save images in postmeta table with post_id.

Comment: @nishant WordPress stores the images (not the physical image, but the relational data associated with it) in both the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) in conjunction with [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php). Then use [wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) to add them to the WordPress database.

**Note:** I was not able to test this, but this is the general concept.

```
// Get WP uploads dir
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Init recursive Obj
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($wp_upload_dir['path']);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    // get filetype for attachment meta
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $file->getPathname(), null );
    // attachment meta
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $filename, 
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    // Insert the attachment.
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );
}
```

Comment: This would go in your theme's functions.php file. But I recommend strongly that you do not do this on a live site until you've tested it in a more secure environment. At the very least, back up your site first. This iterates through your uploads directory and creates an attachment for each file it finds.

Comment: After all those fake copied wordpress sites, so still keeps the solution. Wish I came here first.

Answer (score 0):

When I was migrating a site with more than 55345 articles with images, I  wrote some pure PHP scripts  that perform   migration, and then inserted images as follows (based on the [explanation given by jackreichert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719567/)):

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$save_path = $uploads['basedir'].'/importecms/'.$new_filename;

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $artdata, $save_path, $post_id );

if ($attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $save_path)) {
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
}

$rows_affected = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'postmeta', array('post_id' => $post_id, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'meta_value' => $attach_id));
```